# jQuery table in table length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have two html tables:

```
<table id="tabA">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <table id="tabB">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, if I use `$("#tabA tr").length` I receive 3 instead of 2. I want to count only tabA length.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$("#tabA > tbody > tr").length`. You selector returns ALL tr elements within tabA, not just its direct descendants.

Here's a [reference to child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$("#tabA > tbody > tr").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `direct child` selector:

```
$("#tabA > tr").length
```

Or `children` method:

```
$("#tabA").children('tr').length
```

However browsers add `tbody` wrapper for `tr` elements and `direct child` selector and `children` method do not return a proper value, you can code:

```
$("#tabA > tbody > tr").length
```

Comment: hmm both of them retun 0;
I've added simple function to button under table:
function klik(){
//alert($("#tabA > tr").length);
alert($("#tabA").children('tr').length)
}

Comment: @MacUmatik Yes, use the third one.